# Searching for bikeable offensive town names in Europe like "Fucking"

Tags: europe, routes, destinations, bicycles

Last summer I did a bicycle tour from `Fucking` in Germany to `Petting` in Austria. (I know most people normally do it the other way round)

[image]

On the way you can take a lot of funny pictures.

[image]

The white sign below is German and the English translation of the text is: Please - not so fast.

Are there other towns in Europe with English names that have a rude name, so that I can do more tours like that. By rude names I'm referring to names that are obscene, disrespectful or names that are violating a taboo. Ideally, the villages should be close to each other so that I can do a bike tour.

I tried to search more of these towns in Google maps by just trying out random offensive words. Obviously this is not a very good choice and I couldn't find any other village. What could I do instead? Where can I find resources that will help me to find bikeable offensive towns in Europe?

Comment: This is essentially a list question in its current form and cannot have 'one right answer'. Edit instead to ask for a *resource* that lists such towns and then perhaps this would be okay.

Comment: I don't think there are enough towns to fill a whole list, but I see the problem and I have edited my question.

Comment: rude in what language? A word that in one language is rude can have a completely different meaning and pronunciation in another.

Comment: I thought I have included it in the question, but obviously it is missing. I'm talking about English names.

Comment: Be sure to go through [Condom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condom,_Gers) first.

Comment: The map shows the country-village relation inversed to your first sentence ... up until your last edit it was fine. Why did you change that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Searching Google for "rude place names" turned up [this list](http://www.i-r-genius.com/rudeplaces.html), which has lots of entries for Europe.

This might be useful in conjunction with a [traveling](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/maps/index.html) [salesman](http://gebweb.net/optimap/) solver, to compute an efficient route between several of the points.

Comment: Migrate to Stack Overflow? d-;

Comment: +1 for mentioning that google is also a good resource for travel questions!

Comment: Why is `Tös` regarded offensive in that list?

Comment: @Pekka: http://toss.urbanup.com/829451.  (It's specifically British slang.)

Comment: @Nate ahhh, I didn't make that connection. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I would accept this as an answer, but the problem is, i still don´t have a second tour as the one I did from Fucking to Petting.

Answer (score 10):

What immediately sprang to mind was not as rude as your opening question, but will still upset people in the Bible Belt of the US and probably a few other people too I suppose:

[**Hell, Norway**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell,_Norway)

[image: just for the hell of it]
<sup>Thanks to Wikipedia & WikiMedia Commons for the [photo](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hell2.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Is there a highway to Hell ?

Comment: @Josay: [Route E6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E06), runs _through_ Hell.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this [came up on reddit today](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/3kr76z/it_only_takes_9_hours/) and it was perfectly relevant.  Not necessarily 'offensive' but if you're trying to do a progressive roadtrip with a theme, here are the steps[image]

If you go to the [comments thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/3kr76z/it_only_takes_9_hours/) there are some other similarly themed towns that people suggest in Europe.

Comment: Have a fun trip!

Comment: Or, if you're conservative and want to make the trip a whole lot longer, swap the final two.